# How to improve performance of String.split?

Tags: java, string

I have large (100GB) `CSV` files that I periodically want to convert/reduce.

Each line is separated by a newline, where each line represents a record that I want to convert into a new record.

I therefore first have to split the line, extract my desired fields (+ convert some with logic), and save again as a reduced csv.

Each line contains `2500-3000` chars separated by a `^`, with about `1000` fields.
But I need only approx `120` fields from that split.

I discovered that the actual line splitting takes most of the processing time. I'm thus trying to find the best split method for one line.

My benchmark on a sample size of 10GB is as follows:

approx 5mins:

```
static final Pattern.compile("\\^");
String[] split = pattern.split(line);
```

2min37s:

```
String split[] = string.split("\\^");
```

2min18s (approx 12% faster than string.split()):

```
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, "\\^");
String[] split = new String[tokenizer.countTokens()];
int j = 0;
while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
    split[j] = tokenizer.nextToken();
    j++;
}
```

Question: could there be more room for improvement?

Comment: How long of lines are we looking at? A file with ten million lines that are 50 characters each should be a lot easier to deal with in the abstract than a file with 50 lines that ten million characters each. The latter will push the limits of Java's string type.

Comment: See my update, approx 3k chars per line

Comment: Have you tried `String.indexOf()` and `String.substring()`?

Comment: Not necessarily answering your question - any reason not to use a proper CSV reader?

Comment: Did not try `indexOf` because the CSV fields are NOT fixed length. Not using a CSV reader because each library has another overhead, plus having not control on the split method.

Answer (score 1):

If the first 120 fields/columns in a line/row are relevant, it may be better to use a "limited" edition of [`String::split(String delim, int limit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,int)) which will split only for these ~10% of the columns.

```java
// keep relevant 120 fields + 1 field for the tail part
String[] properFields = string.split("\\^", 121);
```

---

**Update**

If there is a prefix of N fields to be skipped and the next M fields need to be processed, a regular expression may be used to define parts of the line and then only the important part should be picked up.

The latter may be implemented using `Stream<MatchResult>` retrieved via `Scanner` or `Matcher`

```java
String str = "aaa^bbb^ccc^11^22^33^44^55^xyz\r\npp^qqq^sss^99^88^77^66^55^$313";

// N = M = 3
Pattern line = Pattern.compile("(?<prefix>(([^^\\r\\n]+\\^){3}))(?<body>(([^^\\r\\n]+\\^?){0,3})).*\\R?");
Pattern field = Pattern.compile("\\^"); // caret-separated fields

System.out.println("matcher results");
line.matcher(str)
    .results()
    .map(mr -> mr.group(4))
    .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split("\\^")))
    .forEach(System.out::println);

System.out.println("scanner findall");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(str);
scan.findAll(line)
    .map(mr -> mr.group(4))
    .flatMap(field::splitAsStream)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
matcher results
11
22
33
99
88
77
scanner findall
11
22
33
99
88
77
```

---

However, regular expressions may also affect performance, so the simplest way to handle large strings may be to implement custom method to return substring between N and N + M occurrence of the delimiter:

```java
public static String substring(char delim, int from, int to, String line) {
    int index = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int n = line.length();
    for (; index < n && count < from; index++) {
        if (line.charAt(index) == delim) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    int indexFrom = index;
    for (; index < n && count < to; index++) {
        if (line.charAt(index) == delim) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return line.substring(indexFrom, index);
}

System.out.println("scanner plain");
scan = new Scanner(str);
while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(substring('^', 3, 6, scan.nextLine()));
}
```

Output:

```
scanner plain
11^22^33^
99^88^77^
```

Comment: Great idea, unfortunately the fields are distributed over the full length. Anyways, do you know a way that I could only extract parts of the String between eg delimiter 350 - 450 (not index!)? I could then extract only the string portions of the fields to extract, and split only parts of the string. But how could I extract string parts between nth and nth+X delimiter index?